# Escaping line break (endline) from PHP variable for Javascript usage

Tags: php, javascript

heres my code :

```
<td onclick="openFile('<?php echo htmlentities ($row['name'])?>','
                      <?php echo htmlentities ($row['content'])?>')">
    <a href="#nf" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $row['name']?></a></td>
```

as there is an endline char in $row['content']:

> openFile('wow','wow                   wow
>
> wow ');

and when browser cant find an ending qoutes in the same line it throws an

error(SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]).

Any solution for this ?

Comment: Do you need the line break in that string? If not, you can just remove it with a simple replace.

Comment: i need that line break so cant replace it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove it by replacing it with nothing,

```
str_replace("\n","",$row['name']);
```

If you need your line break to be in your JS string you can double escape it,

```
str_replace("\n","\\n",$row['name']);
```

Comment: <?php echo str_replace("\n","\\n",htmlentities ($row['content']));?>     it worked for me , thanx alot

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue like this before. **json_encode** in PHP and **JSON.parse()** in JS helped me resolve this. In your case, I would use this code:

```
<td onclick="openFile('<?php echo htmlentities ($row['name'])?>','
                  <?php echo json_encode($row['content'])?>')">
<a href="#nf" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $row['name']?></a></td>
```

Then on your openFile() function, that is where Im gonna parse ***content*** parameter using JSON.parse() like this:

```
function openFile(name, content){
     content = JSON.parse(content);

     ....
     // your codes here

}
```