# update text area using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to update data using jquery but it fails in case of textarea having enter in it, which is represented by \r\n in mysql.

my code for update function is.

```
<td><i class="fa fa-edit" onclick="upd('<?php echo $fetch_news ['title']; ?>',
                                                          '<?php echo $fetch_news ['detail']; ?>',
                                                          '<?php echo $fetch_news ['date']; ?>',
                                                          '<?php echo $fetch_news ['id']; ?>'
                                                          )"></i></td>
```

and my update function is

```
function upd(title,detail,date,id)
{
  $("#newsTitle").val(title);
  $("#newsDetails").val(detail);
  $("#newsDate").val(date);
  $("#id").val(id);
}
```

my text area input is

```
<div class="form-group"><textarea id="newsDetails" name="newsDetails" title="News Location (less than 200 words)" placeholder="News Details (less than 200 words)" required="" class="form-control"></textarea></div>
```

this code works fine if there is no enter pressed while inserting textarea data

the error i get is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

my insert function is

```
$(function () {
      $("#form").on("submit", function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "extra/logical.php?pg=news&tsk=ins",
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                  $("#showdata").html(data);
                  $("#newsTitle").val('');
                  $("#newsDetails").val('');
                  $("#newsDate").val('');
                  $("#id").val('');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

and insert query is

```
$ins="insert into news set title='".$_POST['newsTitle']."',
                                        detail='".$_POST['newsDetails']."',
                                        date='".$_POST['newsDate']."'
                                        ";
        mysqli_query($conn,$ins);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use htmlspecialchars before saving into database, also, could you show the code of saving into MySQL?

Comment: The issue is the fact the enter is being added in the HTML markup so it is adding an enter into your event listener....  You need to escape it.

Comment: @MyLibary see code of saving into MySQL. I updated

Comment: @epascarello how to escape this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709517/escaping-line-break-endline-from-php-variable-for-javascript-usage

Comment: @epascarello thanks. str_replace("\r\n","\\r\\n",$fetch_news ['detail']); solved my issue

Comment: Please see my answer, or any other source dealing with the issue of SQL Injections. As written, your database and website is guaranteed to be hacked by someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default action of pressing enter in the `textarea` with an event listener.

```html
<textarea placeholder="You can not press enter"></textarea>
<script>
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==13){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
</script>
```

On the server-side, with PHP, you should replace all the line breaks with an empty String so the insertion will not fail (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709517/escaping-line-break-endline-from-php-variable-for-javascript-usage#answer-13709585) answer).

```
str_replace("\r\n", "", "your insertion statement string");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, @epascarello is correct in stating that you need to escape all data going into your database. You are also doing it in an extremely unsafe way, guaranteed to be hacked. Creating your SQL-statements that way opens your code up for something called SQL Injection, and is probably the most common way a website is hacked.

You need to use prepared statements and safeguard your code saving the data, as well as encode the data going in.

As per the examples in [this guide](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared) and the explanations given there, PDO is the only safe way to handle user input that is being saved to a database. This is because of the way the prepared statements are *prepared* on the database server, before you put your data into the query.

As for code, look at this for saving the data:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'myDatabase';
$username = 'awesomeUser';
$pass = 'someTotallySecretPassword';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";

$opt = [ PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $opt);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO news SET title = :title, details = :details, date = :date');
$stmt->execute([
    'title' => urlencode($_POST["newsTitle"]), 
    'details' => urlencode($_POST["newsDetails"]),
    'date' => $_POST["newsDate"]
]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

I am going to advice you to also create the date yourself, on the server, either in SQL or in PHP, unless your use case needs the user to be able to insert a date different than the creation time of the news-article you are creating. If the user does have a need to insert an arbitrary date, you need to do some validation on that as well, to make sure it is valid.

Now, when you need to get the data out again, you need to decode the data from the database with javascript:

```
function decode(text)
{
    return decodeURIComponent(text.replace(/\+/g,' '));
}

function upd(title,detail,date,id)
{
  $("#newsTitle").val( decode(title) );
  $("#newsDetails").val( decode(detail) );
  $("#newsDate").val( date );
  $("#id").val( id );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a useful info. I will work on it. Also tell me what if i use mysqli_real_escape_string() while insertion instead of PDO.

Comment: @AnilSangwa Well, it IS better, but still open to some exploits. Prepared statements are preprocessed by the server, and that ensures that the query itself cannot be altered simply by inserting text. And altering the query is the heartbof sql injections.

Comment: my database connection is $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','lucentsapi') or die('failed to connect'); what do i need to change this? if so, why?

Comment: @AnilSangwa If you look at the code sample I gave you, you can see the variables that make up the information in your connection string. 
`$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'password';
$db = 'lucentsapi';
`

Comment: @AnilSangwa The reason you need to change your connection info is so you can connect using the PDO-objects instead. It has a different syntax for connecting to the database, but it still uses MySQL drives under the hood, as per the `$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";`

Comment: Will implement and let you know